# how to develop Dynamic height UITableViewCell containing a SwiftUI View

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swiftui, uikit

The height of cell should get updated based on the content of that SwiftUI View. When That cell gets visible, an API is hit to fetch data, that data is what configures the SwiftUI View and the height of that swiftUI View is determined accordingly. But, How do I update the height of my UITableViewCell also post configuring my SwiftUI View?

........

I am doing this in the UITableViewCell to get my SwiftUI View added to the contentView of my UITableViewCell

```
    let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: MyCustomSwiftUIView(viewModel: MyCustomSwiftUIViewModel(productCode: "123")))
    let swiftuiView = vc.view!

//setConstraintsOfSubview - giving top, bottom, left, right constraint of 0 with the contentView
    contentView.setConstraintsOfSubview(swiftuiView)
```

for iOS 16 onwards: we can use UIHostingConfiguration. How Do we handle for iOS 15 and below?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc22/10072

Comment: Thanks @loremipsum , But UIHostingConfiguration is for iOS 16 onwards. How Do we handle for iOS 15 and below?

Comment: May be convert the table view to SwiftUI.

Comment: working on a legacy codebase, so that wouldn't be possible!